# Include multiple modules on PyDev project

Tags: python, module, pydev

So, I want to input previously created classes in my current Python project.

For this purpose I created a folder called `lib` and I create one `__init__.py` file in it.
My file structure looks like this

```
project_folder
    lib
        class1_folder
            class1.py
        class2_folder
            class2.py
     _init_.py
     project_script.py
```

In the `__init__.py` file located in the main project folder, I have 2 lines of code.

```
from class1_folder import class1
from class2_folder import class2
```

I want to be able to use the classes that I implemented in my `project_script.py`. How would I be able to call them if they are nested so deeply? 
In project_script, I do the following `from lib.class1_folder.class1 import *` But I get an `ImportError: No module named class1_folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `__init__.py` file to each folder which should be treated as a package (for your example, they should be added to `class1_folder` and `class2_folder`).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is import the file class1.py, by saying import class1, what you actually need to do is import the class from within the file class1.py (may I recommend renaming your files; they make things a little confusing:) ). So, let's say, for example, that your classes are named Dog and Cat (Just to use something completely different, as to avoid confusion), you would need to use:

```
from class1 import Dog
from class2 import Cat
```

Just keep in mind though, the above only works if all of your files are in the same directory, so I would recommend keeping them all in the same directory.

One more thing, in case this is still confusing, when I'm writing "from class1 import Dog", that class1 stands for class1.py, it just doesn't have the file extension at the end. It does not stand for the actual name of the class.

Comment: Can't it be done with the lib folder? The issue here is that I want to create one unified module to use in many of my projects. I have implemented specific data types and IO functions for the needs of my work. If I have all these scripts in 1 project folder, then the whole project would be very messy...